# php preg_match value within multiple div

Tags: preg-match

I want to extract the version number of a webserver. the version number is showed on the admin login page.

i tried this:

```
$content = file_get_contents('URL/login.jsp');

preg_match("/<div class=\"product-version\".*div>/", $content);

echo "content: $content";
```

It does show the version number but also a large part of the rest of the page.

part of the page i want to have preg_match look in:

```
<div class="product-logo" style="background-image:url(images/product/icon-system-admin.png)">
<div class="product-version">10.3</div>
</div>
</h2>
```

Is this possible? or to edit the preg_match to just use the 4 characters after product-version is found?

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: `preg_match('~<div class="product-version">(.+?)</div>~', $content, $m); echo $m[1];`

Answer (score 0):

@Toto that solved it, thanks!

Next thing is to get this working for a bunch of urls.
Want to have the script read urlcustomers.txt in the same directory and show all the version of the webserver for each customer in a table.